# Clip Path Buttons For Circular Nav

Tags: html, css

I need to make a circular nav with a transparent center and buttons shaped like the bars around this Iron Man thing.

[image: Example]

Below is my attempt using clip path... is there a way to do curves to make this easier, or must I draw many more points to make this look good?

CSS

```
.circle-new-btn {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(52% 21%, 57% 22%, 61% 24%, 65% 28%, 68% 31%, 59% 48%, 56% 46%, 53% 44%, 49% 43%, 45% 42%, 41% 44%, 38% 47%, 34% 50%, 32% 28%, 36% 25%, 40% 24%, 46% 22%);
clip-path: polygon(52% 21%, 57% 22%, 61% 24%, 65% 28%, 68% 31%, 59% 48%, 56% 46%, 53% 44%, 49% 43%, 45% 42%, 41% 44%, 38% 47%, 34% 46%, 32% 28%, 36% 25%, 40% 24%, 46% 22%);
}

.circle-new-btn:hover {
    background: rgba(111,111,0,1.00);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="circle-new-btn"></div>
```

Comment: If it were me, I'd look to SVG instead of pure CSS on this one.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but I have zero experience with SVG and cannot find a good tutorial on how to draw shapes out of the ordinary with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea how you can create this shape using CSS:

```css
.box {
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 padding:20px 0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 background:
  radial-gradient(circle at 50% 160%,transparent 45%,blue 44.5%,blue 85%,transparent 85%);
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 75% 90%, 25% 90%);
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 75% 90%, 25% 90%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 Some text
</div>
```

Then you can simply apply some rotation to place the buttons around the big circle.

Comment: Thank you so much, Temani! I was struggling with this one thing for awhile, now I can move on with my life because of your kindness. Thanks again!